# How to add NugetPackages to Shared Project?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am creating a crossPlatform Project. I want to add the sqlite-net and the sqlite-net extension to my shared Project, it seems that i can't add nuget packages to my shared project. is there a way to add it or is ther another way to use sqlite extension in the shared project without importing the nuget package

Comment: what is your shared project targetting? mono or .net core/standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/70403/add-nuget-packages-is-disabled

> When you create a Forms app, the template will ask you if you want to
>   use a Shared project or a Portable Class Library for your shared code.
>   you most likely chose Shared project which is NOT a real project in
>   that it doesn't compile to a DLL like other project types. therefore,
>   you don't add nuget packages to a Shared project. the Shared project
>   uses the nuget packages added to the iOS and Android projects.
>
> think of a Shared project as a collection of source code that
>   automatically gets transparently copied to each of the real projects
>   that use it as if that shared source code was physically part of the
>   real projects.
>
> so if your shared code doesn't compile due to a missing nuget than you
>   must add that nuget to both of your iOS and Android real projects.